# Can I use datepicker on class and then on id for the same element?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have three input fields that use datepicker:

```
    <input id="issue_date" name="issue_date" class="form-control date_class" type="text" required />
    <input id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" class="form-control date_class" type="text" required />
```

Can I use jquery like this (the code I try to apply on IDs doesn't seem to be working):

```
  $(".date_class").datepicker({
    monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mart", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Avg", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec" ],
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
  });

  $("#issue_date").datepicker({ 
    yearRange: "-110:+0",
    maxDate: "today"
  });

  $("#expiry_date").datepicker({
    minDate: "today"
  });
```

I do realize that I can use only the ID selectors, but I wanted do shorten the code. Am I doing something wrong or I can't do it at all this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the plugin only once.

One solution is to use $.extend() to create the options like

```js
var opts = {
  monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mart", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Avg", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
};

$("#issue_date").datepicker($.extend({}, opts, {
  yearRange: "-110:+0",
  maxDate: "today",
}));

$("#expiry_date").datepicker($.extend({}, opts, {
  minDate: "today"
}));
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="issue_date" name="issue_date" class="form-control date_class" type="text" required />
<input id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" class="form-control date_class" type="text" required />
```

---

Another is to use the options method

```js
$(".date_class").datepicker({
  monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mart", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Avg", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});

$("#issue_date").datepicker('option', {
  yearRange: "-110:+0",
  maxDate: "today"
});

$("#expiry_date").datepicker('option', {
  minDate: "today"
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="issue_date" name="issue_date" class="form-control date_class" type="text" required />
<input id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" class="form-control date_class" type="text" required />
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you, so helpful!